# GridBagLayout not working as expected

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

i  was coding Address Book  GUI  using GridBagLayout . problem is that  when i set gridx and gridy  that does not work  it looks as there is no  layout used and components fall in center of the Frame . i am not pasting whole code just a small piece of code for 1 `JButton`  to  let you see  what  is happening  .. please see the  code and gudide me how to fix  it ,  right now button is falling in center of the  `JFrame`

I am just beginner so please dont mind   if   foolish style code or any problem like that

```
public class rect  
{
 JFrame frame ; 
 JPanel panel1 ; 
 JButton b1;
 GridBagConstraints gbc; 

 public  rect()
{
    panel1 = new JPanel();  
    panel1.setSize(300,300);
    panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    frame= new JFrame("Address ?ooK "); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);


    b1= new JButton () ;
    b1.setText("Hello ");
    gbc.gridx=1; 
    gbc.gridy=0; 

    panel1.add(b1, gbc) ; 

    frame.add(panel1);
    panel1.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Where is it supposed to be? Try to set `weightx/weight` to `1.0` and change `anchor` to `GridBagLayout.NORTH`... and see what happens ;-) I recommend to carefully read GBL documentation and tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting

```
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
```

for `GridBagConstraints`, you are not setting absolute co-ordinates like you would if you using *absolute positioning*. Instead, you are setting the grid cell where the component will reside. In this sample application above, there is only one component so there is only one grid cell so the `JButton` will be center positioned by default.

To highlight this fact we could add set the anchor to `NORTH` and add another button, creating 2 grid cells:

```
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;

gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;

panel1.add(new JButton("Hello"), gbc);

gbc.gridx = 2; // now a 2nd cell exists
panel1.add(new JButton("Test"), gbc);
```

Notice we also set `weightx` and `weighty` so that the button could take their positions at the top of the `JFrame`:

[image: GridBagLayout with 2 NORTH-Anchored Components]

Comment: why should i use this one ,  gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
i mean if i am  coding whole swing application  instead of  1 button  still should i use it ?

Comment: Was `NORTH` anchor to show how to place the button(s) at the top of the container. If you have more components, they will fill the grid cells so you may not need an anchor then.

Answer (score 0):

There are some details missing from what your end goal is, but:

Your frame doesn't have a layout manager so your JPanel is going to end up in the middle of your frame. Whatever contents (e.g. JButtons) you add to the panel is going to be layed out according to GridBagLayout (but your frame doesn't know how to position your pane because your frame doesn't have a lay out manager). Think of your frame as a container, and your pane as another container.

Set a GridBagLayout for your frame similar to how you have it set up for your pane.

---

Also, your frame and your panel are set to exactly the same size -

```
panel1.setSize(300,300);
...
frame.setSize(300, 300);
```

You probably want to make your frame bigger to actually see the effects of `panel1`'s positioning change according to the frame's layout manager.

Comment: But i did see  GridBagLayout  set for JPanel   here            http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: ok i did add this                              frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());  still it does not work ..

Comment: @SikanderNawaz did you specify the constraints for your frame as you did for your jpanel?

Comment: @SikanderNawaz also see updated comments about the sizes issue for your frame and jpanel.

Comment: How should i add it for Frame . i mean i did add for panel gbc then used this one for gridx etc , so should i add different one for frame and panel as gbc1   and gbc  if so which one to use for gridx?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a different layout such as BorderLayout. For instance you can then

```
panel1 = new JPanel();  
panel1.setSize(300,300);
panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

frame= new JFrame("Address ?ooK "); 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(300, 300);
b1= new JButton ("Hello") ;

panel1.add(gbc) ; 

frame.add(panel1,BorderLayout.CENTER));
frame.add(b1,BorderLayout.PAGE_END));
panel1.setVisible(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```